# Error: for property 'guitarist': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: java, spring, aop

[This is the example I'm working on](https://github.com/Apress/pro-spring-5/tree/master/chapter05/proxyfactorybean)

The problem is I get errors from this code like:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'documentaristOne' defined in class path resource .... for property 'guitarist': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support...

Interface:

```java
public interface Singer {
    public void sing();    
}
```

Classes:

```java
public class GrammyGuitarist implements Singer{

@Override
public void sing() {

    System.out.println("sing: Gravity is working against me\n" +
            "And gravity wants to bring me down");
}

public void sing(Guitar guitar) {
    System.out.println("play: " + guitar.play());
}

public void talk(){
    System.out.println("talk");
}

}
```

```java
public class Documentarist {

protected GrammyGuitarist guitarist;

public void execute() {
    guitarist.sing();
    guitarist.talk();
}

public void setGuitarist(GrammyGuitarist guitarist) {
    this.guitarist = guitarist;
}
}
```

```java
public class ProxyFactoryBeanDemo {
public static void main(String... args) {
    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    ctx.load("spring/app-context-xml.xml");
    ctx.refresh();

    Documentarist documentaristOne = ctx.getBean("documentaristOne", Documentarist.class);
    Documentarist documentaristTwo = ctx.getBean("documentaristTwo", Documentarist.class);

    System.out.println("Documentarist One >>");
    documentaristOne.execute();

    System.out.println("\nDocumentarist Two >> ");
    documentaristTwo.execute();
}
}
```

app-xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean id="johnMayer" class="com.apress.prospring5.ch5.GrammyGuitarist"/>
    <bean id="advice" class="com.apress.prospring5.ch5.AuditAdvice"/>

    <bean id="documentaristOne" class="com.apress.prospring5.ch5.Documentarist"
          p:guitarist-ref="proxyOne"/>

    <bean id="proxyOne" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean"
          p:target-ref="johnMayer" p:interceptorNames-ref="interceptorAdviceNames"/>

    <util:list id="interceptorAdviceNames">
        <value>advice</value>
    </util:list>


    <bean id="documentaristTwo" class="com.apress.prospring5.ch5.Documentarist"
          p:guitarist-ref="proxyTwo"/>

    <bean id="proxyTwo" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean"
          p:target-ref="johnMayer" p:interceptorNames-ref="interceptorAdvisorNames">
    </bean>

    <util:list id="interceptorAdvisorNames">
        <value>advisor</value>
    </util:list>

    <bean id="advisor" class="org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor"
          p:advice-ref="advice">
        <property name="pointcut">
            <bean class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut"
                  p:expression="execution(* sing*(..))"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

As I see the issue is in an attempt to initialize the **GenericXmlApplicationContext** In app-xml the row:

```
<bean id="documentaristOne" class="com.apress.prospring5.ch5.Documentarist"
      p:guitarist-ref="proxyOne"/>
```

Trying to create a **documentaristOne** instance of **Documentarist** but for property **guitarist** we provide not the bean instance of **GrammyGuitarist** but a proxy one. Yes, **proxyOne** has ref to **GrammyGuitarist** via "johnMayer":

```
<bean id="proxyOne" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean"
      p:target-ref="johnMayer" p:interceptorNames-ref="interceptorAdviceNames"/>
```

But as I see JAVA/Spring doesn't want to accept it. Is it possible somehow to cast type proxy to the target type? If no, what to do then  to make this code work?

Full stack below:

```
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'documentaristOne' defined in class path resource [ch5/ProxyFactoryBeanDemo/app-context-xml.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7 implementing ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.Singer,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.GrammyGuitarist' for property 'guitarist'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7 implementing ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.Singer,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.GrammyGuitarist' for property 'guitarist': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'documentaristOne' defined in class path resource [ch5/ProxyFactoryBeanDemo/app-context-xml.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7 implementing ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.Singer,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.GrammyGuitarist' for property 'guitarist'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7 implementing ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.Singer,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.GrammyGuitarist' for property 'guitarist': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.main(ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7 implementing ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.Singer,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.GrammyGuitarist' for property 'guitarist'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7 implementing ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.Singer,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.GrammyGuitarist' for property 'guitarist': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:604)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1748)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7 implementing ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.Singer,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.GrammyGuitarist' for property 'guitarist': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:262)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:585)
    ... 15 more
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: Can you post the full error stacktrace please and not some of it with ... ?

Comment: I've added the full stack. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: You also have an interface `Singer` where in the code you have posted is nowhere used, however it is mentioned in the stacktrace you posted `Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7 implementing ch5.ProxyFactoryBeanDemo.Singer...`. Are you sure the code posted is the one you are trying to run?

Comment: GrammyGuitarist implements it. I edited, not know why it was missed.

Comment: I cloned the example repository and ran the application. It works beautifully. You must have changed something in order to break it.

Comment: I removed the Singer implementation from the GrammyGuitarist and made method Sing() just as method of GrammyGuitarist. As it is on GitHub. It works fine. But why it doesn't accept interface, as it is shown in the book (Pro Spring 5), I have no idea.

Comment: Oh, so your own implementation is different from the project you linked to. In that case, please fork the original repository and share a link to **your** version. I tested the one you linked to. How can I know what you changed. You cannot expect me to manually compare what you posted here to the repository after cloning it. I also cannot know what else you might have changed, which you did not show here, e.g. configuration.

Comment: OK, you did not update your question with an MCVE. Maybe you want to ask a new question in the future. But I kindly request you to accept my answer to this one, because I answered the question with regard to the example you linked to at the beginning of your question. Just click on the grey checkmark beside the answer, making it green. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is that Spring Core (not Spring Boot) by default creates JDK proxies, if the target class implements an interface. This is also true for the `ProxyFactoryBean` example you tried to modify. I.e., as soon as you make `GrammyGuitarist` implement `Singer`, you no longer get a CGLIB proxy but a JDK proxy. The JDK proxy is not a subclass of `GrammyGuitarist`, which means it cannot be cast to that class, but code and configuration refer to that class explicitly, not simply to `Singer`. Therefore,

- either you need to make the bean type `Singer`
- or you configure Spring to create CGLIB proxies by using `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>` in the `<beans>` section and `p:proxyTargetClass="true"` in the two bean configurations using the proxy factory bean.

I am showing you how to change the [XML configuration](https://github.com/Apress/pro-spring-5/blob/94998e2dc6a1086b0bd3225ab204e7550d7ea136/chapter05/proxyfactorybean/src/main/resources/spring/app-context-xml.xml).

This is the diff:

```
diff --git a/chapter05/proxyfactorybean/src/main/java/com/apress/prospring5/ch5/GrammyGuitarist.java b/chapter05/proxyfactorybean/src/main/java/com/apress/prospring5/ch5/GrammyGuitarist.java
--- a/chapter05/proxyfactorybean/src/main/java/com/apress/prospring5/ch5/GrammyGuitarist.java   (revision Staged)
+++ b/chapter05/proxyfactorybean/src/main/java/com/apress/prospring5/ch5/GrammyGuitarist.java   (date 1630836290986)
@@ -1,11 +1,12 @@
 package com.apress.prospring5.ch5;
 
 import com.apress.prospring5.ch2.common.Guitar;
+import com.apress.prospring5.ch2.common.Singer;
 
 /**
  * Created by iuliana.cosmina on 4/9/17.
  */
-public class GrammyGuitarist {
+public class GrammyGuitarist implements Singer {
    public void sing() {
        System.out.println("sing: Gravity is working against me\n" +
                "And gravity wants to bring me down");
diff --git a/chapter05/proxyfactorybean/src/main/resources/spring/app-context-xml.xml b/chapter05/proxyfactorybean/src/main/resources/spring/app-context-xml.xml
--- a/chapter05/proxyfactorybean/src/main/resources/spring/app-context-xml.xml  (revision Staged)
+++ b/chapter05/proxyfactorybean/src/main/resources/spring/app-context-xml.xml  (date 1630838376150)
@@ -2,12 +2,17 @@
 
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
+       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
-        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
+        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
+        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
+        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
+
+    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
 
     <bean id="johnMayer" class="com.apress.prospring5.ch5.GrammyGuitarist"/>
     <bean id="advice" class="com.apress.prospring5.ch5.AuditAdvice"/>
@@ -16,7 +21,8 @@
           p:guitarist-ref="proxyOne"/>
 
     <bean id="proxyOne" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean"
-          p:target-ref="johnMayer" p:interceptorNames-ref="interceptorAdviceNames"/>
+          p:target-ref="johnMayer" p:interceptorNames-ref="interceptorAdviceNames"
+          p:proxyTargetClass="true"/>
 
     <util:list id="interceptorAdviceNames">
         <value>advice</value>
@@ -27,7 +33,8 @@
           p:guitarist-ref="proxyTwo"/>
 
     <bean id="proxyTwo" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean"
-          p:target-ref="johnMayer" p:interceptorNames-ref="interceptorAdvisorNames">
+          p:target-ref="johnMayer" p:interceptorNames-ref="interceptorAdvisorNames"
+          p:proxyTargetClass="true">
     </bean>
 
     <util:list id="interceptorAdvisorNames">
```

And this is the full XML config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean id="johnMayer" class="com.apress.prospring5.ch5.GrammyGuitarist"/>
    <bean id="advice" class="com.apress.prospring5.ch5.AuditAdvice"/>

    <bean id="documentaristOne" class="com.apress.prospring5.ch5.Documentarist"
          p:guitarist-ref="proxyOne"/>

    <bean id="proxyOne" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean"
          p:target-ref="johnMayer" p:interceptorNames-ref="interceptorAdviceNames"
          p:proxyTargetClass="true"/>

    <util:list id="interceptorAdviceNames">
        <value>advice</value>
    </util:list>


    <bean id="documentaristTwo" class="com.apress.prospring5.ch5.Documentarist"
          p:guitarist-ref="proxyTwo"/>

    <bean id="proxyTwo" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean"
          p:target-ref="johnMayer" p:interceptorNames-ref="interceptorAdvisorNames"
          p:proxyTargetClass="true">
    </bean>

    <util:list id="interceptorAdvisorNames">
        <value>advisor</value>
    </util:list>

    <bean id="advisor" class="org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor"
          p:advice-ref="advice">
        <property name="pointcut">
            <bean class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut"
                  p:expression="execution(* sing*(..))"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: I think setting `p:proxyTargetClass="true"` is sufficient, `aop namespace` is not needed. At least that worked for me. [Ref: If the `proxyTargetClass` property of the ProxyFactoryBean has been set to true, then a CGLIB-based proxy will be created.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.RC1/reference/html/ch08s05.html). ----- (Also, try not to directly run the code on this github project. Create your own project and copy the necessary files to your own project. The original project from gitbub just keeps throwing errors.)

Comment: Sorry, but of course I fixed the project on GitHub, because it is what the OP asked about. And I fixed it exactly as explained here. It works and does not throw any errors with my PR. If your experience is any different, either you have another project or did not follow my instructions. So your comment is not very helpful, because my answer is correct. I did not speculate, but I tried. I don't have to say "I think" like you. It works beautifully the way I said.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to let spring beans know which components you are using.
Try adding @Component() annotation above Documentarist GrammyGuitarist class initialization

Comment: Hm...no it didn't help. But the most interesting thing how it works for other? I mean this code is from book and should work.